# Sending mails with ActionMailer without adding new controller / model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, actionmailer

I have a page with the cart which contains one form for user data and items to be sent; this is available to non-registered users so I don't need to store anything in the database (only validate the form), but every article I saw so far is written about sending e-mails on user registration, comment or other action involving it's own controller and model. Basically it has a same structure like contact form.

Should I make new controller where I'll send the message in **create** action or use different approach for this?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question but you shouldn't be adding a controller/model for just firing off emails.  If you have a point in your app where user interaction should trigger an email just add a call to the corresponding Mailer to deliver it right from that action.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Yup, that's exactly what I asked. There's only one form with validations, without any DB interaction.

Comment: Yes at that point you would only decide on whether you want to setup a "form model" to handle that one page's form validations or you can nest those validations in the existing Model if there isn't a ton of code involved.  As for the mailer do as you guessed and don't add controllers/models for it!